# realm access from icorrect thread even if I get another instance

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, realm

I'm trying to retrieve some data & update them in a AsyncTask.
The problem is I get a 
 `Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.` 
error even if I'm updating my realm instance in the async task. 
 Here's my code:

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                // my queries & updates
                return null;
            }
 }.execute();
```

Comment: Please post the code that the stack trace is complaining about and point to the line that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create default insance in `onPreExecute()`  method.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            private Realm mRealm;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // my queries & updates
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Can you shed some light on why this would solve the issue?